# copy to clipboard doesnt work in safari- angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari

I am using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-clipboard) directive to implement copy to clipboard functionality. But this doesnt work with safari. I tried to find an alternative using [this](https://sachinchoolur.github.io/ngclipboard/). But this also doesnt have support for safari. I found in the explanation that "copy/cut operations with execCommand aren't supported on Safari yet (including mobile)".  So I wanted to crosscheck is this functionality actually not possible to be supported on safari. Any leads would help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Copy to clipboard from JavaScript is not supported in Safari, as the ClipboardEvent constructor is not implemented in Safari...

[CanIUse - Clipboard API](http://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard)

Most code relies on something similar to the following:

```js
var copyEvent = new ClipboardEvent('copy',
  { dataType: 'text/plain', data: 'Safari Test' } );
document.dispatchEvent(copyEvent);
```

You might be able to get it working in Safari using `Selection`, hidden elements and script generated events, I have't looked at that approach.

Comment: I couldnt get this working.  Anyway I tried opening github on safari. It turns out that copy git link also doesnt work on safari.  So I dont know if it is worth it to sweat so much upon it.